# Python NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I get a NameError when I attempt to execute the following code with any possible input string in Python 3.0:

```
def onePerLine(str):
    for i in str:
        print(i)

word=input("Enter a phrase or word: ")
onePerLine(word)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Enter a phrase or word: hello

Traceback (most recent call last):File"C:\Users\R\Documents\Python30\func2.py",line 5, in <module> word=input("Enter a phrase or word: ")

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

How do i fix this and get my code to run? 
PS: I'm a newbie to python and to programming in general. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Python 2, so you need to use `raw_input`

```
>>> x = input('')
hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    x = input('')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Using `raw_input`

```
>>> x = raw_input('')
hello
>>> x
'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using python 2 and you need to use `raw_input` instead of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) which evaluate the string and assumes it as a variable name.

> **input([prompt])**
>
> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> ...
>
> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.